# FormHelper::input() creates a drop-down select if fielname has the "_id" suffix

Tags: php, html, cakephp, form-helpers

I have the following line of code on a CakePHP view:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->input(
  'person_id',
  array(
    'label' => false,
    'div' => false,
    'class' => 'form-control search-person'
  )
);
?>
```

I want to create a text input with this line of code, but if the field name has the suffix `_id`, the rendered HTML changes from a text field to a drop-down select.

If I change the prefix to anything else, for example `person_idd` or `abc_idd`, it renders a text input, but if the field name ends with `_id` suffix, it renders a drop-down select, which doesn't allow me to write anything.

Is this some CakePHP feature? How can I avoid this behavior and produce a  text input with a field ending with the `_id` suffix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a CakePHP feature:

> This method will automatically inspect the model field it has been supplied in order to create an appropriate input for that field.

Taken from [Cookbook 2.x: FormHelper: Creating form elements](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#creating-form-elements).

To get a text input, add `'type' => 'text'` to the options array:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('person_id', array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'label' => false, 
    'div' => false, 
    'class' => 'form-control search-person'
)); ?>
```